# Unknow node.js and websockets server stopping. Who revises my code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I've written my application and now I've activated New Relic and it pings my app every 30 mins to keep my server alive (heroku). Otherwise before the server would just idling and then taking a lot of time to restart on the first request.

I'm running a socket.io server and the problem that i'm facing now, is that after a lot of time that the server runs, it gets stuck in answering to the namespaces. The application doesn't give any fatal error, it keeps running but just stops answering.
It keeps working as usual (still detects and log new connected clients), but just doesn't sends the messages.

Nothing weird on the logs.

Could you help to check if I'm doing anything really wrong with my code that I shouldn't do and might create problems? (e.g. too many listeners etc.)

I've made a little summary of my code, so there might be some little stupid syntax errors, but the flow should be this one. Everything is repeated by 4, because I have 4 namespaces and 4 different queries.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var cors = require('cors');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var sensorSocket = io.of('/namespace1'); //This gives back all the sensor at once with just now values.
var oldata = [];
var intervalRefresh=300;

app.use(cors());
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connectionsArray = [];
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx',
    port: xx,
    dateStrings: 'date'
})

//websockets creation/connection

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

http.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('\n\n\n\n listening on port: %s', PORT);
});

io.of('/namespace1').on('connection', function (socket) {
    newconnectionSensors = 1;
    console.log("Client id: %s connected on /sensors", socket.id);
    console.log(io.of('/sensors').sockets.length);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("Just left the ship grrarr : %s", socket.id);
    });
});

io.of('/namespace2').on('connection', function (socket) {
    [..Similar to the previous one..]
});


io.of('/namespace3').on('connection', function (socket) {
    [..Similar to the previous one..]
});


io.of('/namespace4').on('connection', function (socket) {
    [..Similar to the previous one..]
});

//Above here I do the same request every 300ms to the db and if there is any change, sends it into the client.

var CheckDB = setInterval(function (sensorSocket) {
    if (io.of('/namespace1').sockets.length > 0) {
        var query = connection.query('Query...'),

        data = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query
        query
            .on('error', function (err) {
                // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('result', function (result) {
                data.push(result);
            })
            .on('end', function () {
                if ((JSON.stringify(oldata) != JSON.stringify(data)) || newconnection == 1) { //if new data is different than the old data, update the clients
                    io.of('/namespace1').emit('message', dataSensors, io.of('/namespace1').sockets.id);
                    newconnection = 0;
                    oldata = data.slice(0); //copy of data to oldata
                }

            });

    }

}, intervalRefresh);

var CheckDB2 = setInterval(function (sensorSocket) {
        [..Similar to the previous one..]
}, intervalRefresh);

var CheckDB3 = setInterval(function (sensorSocket) {
        [..Similar to the previous one..]
}, intervalRefresh);

var CheckDB4 = setInterval(function (sensorSocket) {
        [..Similar to the previous one..]
}, intervalRefresh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

The real mistake was that I was not having really clear the Non-Blocking concept of NodeJS, so in the code I was not waiting for the answers from the MySQL server and instead I was just throwing queries to the server so the results were going to arrive after hours.

I've fixed by making an escamotage. Basically I added a var (queryexecuting) which is checking if the query has been finish to execute or not.

```
var CheckDB = setInterval(function (sensorSocket) {
    if (io.of('/namespace1').sockets.length > 0 && queryexecuting==0) { //If there are connected clients and there is no query executing.
        queryexecuting=1; //Means the query is working
        var query = connection.query('Query...'),

        data = [];
        query
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('result', function (result) {
                data.push(result);
            })
            .on('end', function () {
                if ((JSON.stringify(oldata) != JSON.stringify(data)) || newconnection == 1) { 
                    io.of('/namespace1').emit('message', dataSensors, io.of('/namespace1').sockets.id);
                    newconnection = 0;
                    oldata = data.slice(0);
                }
                queryexecuting=0; //Means the query has been finished
            });

    }

}, intervalRefresh);
```